# Include main effect when specifying varying coefficient models with GAMM?

Tags: r, modeling, interaction, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to model an interaction between two continuous variables in the GAMM framework using `gamm` in R. For simplicity's sake, I am ignoring the repeated measures aspect of the data in the model examples below.

The model I am currently working with is the varying coefficient model using `by`. I have three variables that are all continuous, a brain measure, age, and a cognition measure. In all the examples I have seen, the model would look like this:

```
brain ~ s(age,by = cognition)
```

However, I know that age has a massive effect on the outcome (a model that only includes `s(age)` is wildly significant), and I am unsure if that will essentially guarantee that this interaction model will be significant. I am wondering if it makes sense to include a separate main effect for age in the model, such as:

```
brain ~ s(age) + s(age,by = cognition)
```

Does this model make sense? It seems intuitive to me, but I haven't seen it done. In this way, I can also easily compare this model to the simpler model that only includes a main effect of age:

`brain ~ s(age)`

Are there problems with this? I am relatively new to GAM, so my intuitions may be off!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to model the interaction this way? On the face of it, your model estimates how the *linear* effect of `cognition` varies as a smooth function of `age`. I can certainly understand reasons for wanting to fit such a model. But a more general model would be a fully smooth interaction `te(age, cognition)` which would be easier to handle (you can decompose to `s(age) + s(cognition) + ti(age, cognition)` for example & test the last term, or use AIc to choose say. 1/2

Comment: That said, I don't see anything wrong with `s(age) + s(age, by = cognition)` in and of itself. I can envisage a concurvity issue if the you can approximate one smooth effect by the other, but you can check for that once you have fitted the model using `concurvity()`.

Comment: Thanks. I had also looked at the bivariate smooth as `s(age) + s(cognition) + s(age,cognition)` but I felt it was an unnecessarily complex model for the data was worried about overfitting. A general question I am interested in is if the smooth form of age varies based on cognitive ability (i.e. do lower functioning individuals fall differ in their developmental trajectory). The varying coefficient model using `by` seemed to address this question while also being a simpler model than the bivariate smooth. I this a correct understanding of the differences between these models?

Comment: I don't think the varying coefficient model is doing that; `s(age,by = cognition)` says allow the *linear* effect of `cognition` to vary smoothly with age. So the model quantifies the effect of `cognition` on the response and how that effect varies smoothly with `age`. You are no more likely to over fit with `te(age, cognition)` than the models you considered - the smoothness penalty will control that. Note you don't want to do `s(age) + s(cognition) + s(age,cognition)`, the last term then should be `ti(age, condition)` otherwise you'll likely hit issues with model instability.

Comment: If you want the smooth effect of `age` to vary with `cognition` then the bivariate smooth using tensor products is a good place to start. A further issue with `s(age, cognition)` is that`age` and `cognition` are on different scales and `s()` ignores this.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo. I have been using `ti(age) + ti(cognition) + ti(age,cognition)`.

Comment: From your explanation, it sounds like with `s(age, by = cognition)`, I am assessing whether the effect of cognition is increasing or decreasing along the smooth of age. So this model would detect if the cognition effect emerged at a certain point along the developmental curve.

Comment: Yes, it would allow you to assess how the effect of cognition on your response changed as a function smooth function of `age`. You could do the same with the bivariate smooth, but that model would include the `age` effect also. Your VC model with `s(age) + s(age,by = cognition)`, which I think would be a starting model if you think `age` is an important predictor of the response. Fit that and the bivariate smooth model and compare the fits, see which does a better job.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your thoughtful advice!